# How to make a cookie use Qt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I  get a cookie from server, and I try to use `QNetworkCookie` create it, but it look different when I  had  got.

The Cookie I get from server like:

```py
PHPSESSID=t2l6v6nrsam9mgenjad6pa56e6;Domain=api.tx1928.com;path=/;Path=/;PHPSESSID=t2l6v6nrhdm9mgenjad6pa56e6;HttpOnly=;rong_im_auth_name=97c8e28aad96e1998cdc8e5fe7adcc65ed346e94c393065c;Max-Age=2592000;rong_im_auth_name=97c8e28aad96e1998cdc8e5fe7adcc65ed346e94c393065c;Expires=Thu, 24 Sep 2020 01:08:31 GMT;
```

I try to use `QNetworkCookie.parseCookies` method to parse it and then use `QNetworkCookieJar` set it,After I send it to server, in my browser I got like this

```
Cookie: PHPSESSID=t2l6v6nrhdm9mgenjad6pa56e6
```

It had lost many message?And so how can I make origin cookie when i get in this case?

**code demo like this:**

```py
class NetManager(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.nm = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.nm.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
        self.set_cookie()
    
    def on_finished(self, reply: QNetworkReply):
        if reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            data = reply.readAll()
            print('data', data)
    
    def set_cookie(self):
        jar =  QNetworkCookieJar()  # type:QNetworkCookieJar
        data = b'PHPSESSID=t2l6v6nrsam9mgenjad6pa56e6;Domain=api.tx1928.com;path=/;Path=/;PHPSESSID=t2l6v6nrhdm9mgenjad6pa56e6;HttpOnly=;rong_im_auth_name=97c8e28aad96e1998cdc8e5fe7adcc65ed346e94c393065c;Max-Age=2592000;rong_im_auth_name=97c8e28aad96e1998cdc8e5fe7adcc65ed346e94c393065c;Expires=Thu, 24 Sep 2020 01:08:31 GMT;'
        cookies = QNetworkCookie.parseCookies(data)
        
        jar.setAllCookies(cookies)
    
        self.nm.setCookieJar(jar)


    def post(self, url):
        #to post some data to site
```

Comment: I don't understand you, could you explain better in addition to providing a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Add a simple class to show it.

Comment: I think _maybe_ you're just seeing browsers' expected behavior around cookies. The cookie-setting header from the server to the browser includes a lot of metadata that the Cookie header sent from browser to server does not.

Comment: @twotwotwo It can work when set `QNetworkRequest..setRawHeader(b'Cookie', data)`, i don't know why `QNetworkAccessManager` can't work in my case.

Comment: I'm trying to say maybe `QNetworkAccessManager` is _working_ and `;Domain=...` and everything after shouldn't be sent back to the server.

Comment: @twotwotwo yes,you are right, but I had test that cookie had domain, path, httpOnly is set in `QNetworkCookie`, it not send to sever.